# Magento: "core.13528" files?

Tags: magento

Some files showed up mysteriously in my Magento shop home folder, they're all named core.13528, core.13529...there's about 40 of them, and all take up to 400MB!!

Does anyone know what do they mean and how did they got there? Can I delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are core dumps - memory images from failed processes. You don't need them unless you are in a position to analyze program crashes with a debugger (or if you submit bug reports to the authors who are).

However, if the numbers (usually process IDs) are consecutive, it looks like your processes *always* crash eventually - this should be a cause of worry.